# how can I generate 10 digit unique number that will be sent to user after registration on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I would like to generate a 10 unique number for a user immediately they Register on the website sent via email and probably they will use the generated number to login to the website

Comment: You can use php function [rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) `rand(1111111111,9999999999);
`

Comment: Always a search before you ask